# Access the output of a function in another block's mask parameters

Tags: matlab, simulink

So I am using `Simulink` and I am trying to incorporate a `fuzzy logic` controller to auto-tune the parameters of my PID. But how do I use the output of a `MATLAB Function` block as the parameters in a PID block?

[image: Overview]

Here I show my function which has the outputs of P, I & D (K_p, K_i & K_d in standard notation). I want to use them inside the PID block mask parameters:

[image: PID Parameters]

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this but I just can't figure it out! Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PID Controller block only allows the P, I and D gains to be entered as parameters (i.e. on the dialog) not as signals (i.e. through inports).

You'll need to implement your own PID.  The [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/pidcontroller.html) shows what the implementation should look like.  You'll need to replace the P, I and D gain blocks by product blocks with your P, I and D input signals feeding into the product blocks.